# Is there a way to cancel "AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()"?

Tags: multithreading

thanks in advance for helping.

I want to cancel the `AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()` at some point in my code (meaning I do not want to block anymore), but I just cann't find the way to do it. Perhaps, it is the logical problem of my program, but I can not think of any other way to break out of the loop as soon as exit signal is given. The following is the code which has the problem:

```
s.Bind(endPoint);  
s.Listen(15);
while (true) {
    thrd = s.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(Accept_Callback), s);
    thrd.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); // it still blocks here when next statement becomde "true"
    if (_syncEvents.ExitThreadEvent.WaitOne(0, false))
    {
       //I want to break out of the loop at this point, it breaks out only when next call coming
        thrd.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
        s.Close();
        break;
    } 
}
```

Please help, thanks!

Aaron Chen

Answer (score 3):

You could use a manual reset event:

```
    ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] { evt, thrd.AsyncWaitHandle };

    WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles);
```

Then, from another thread, call:

```
    evt.Set();
```

to release the socket.

Comment: Thanks Paul Keister,

I will try that and let you know how it is going, thank you!

Aaron

Comment: Paul,

Thanks for solving my problem.

Aaron